# HTML5 Video : no compatible source was found for this media

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, video, video.js

I want to implement a funcitonlity in which if a user clicks a video link, that video shud start getting played.

I created a standalone application for demo purpose having below code :

[image]

But now if iam using the same code in real time then the video is not getting played. Iam getting a message "no compatible source was found for this media".
The application code is :

[image]

Please help.

Comment: when you debug what source URI is it trying to load?

Comment: i have debugged, the src which it is setting to is same as we wudve given directly.  If iam directly assigning the src and type in source then its working fine but if iam assigning programmatically then its not.

Comment: How did you solve this problem ? I am experiencing the same.

Comment: if i remember correctly, i needed to configure the MIME types in IIS for Video. S basically if you can get hold of your IIS either at local or in the deployed IP and confidure the MIME types for Video. You will have to use **inetmgr** command